# Flutter- Error with Drawer and Listview.Builder()

Tags: flutter

Here's my code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
//import 'package:location/location.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _Home createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
  //declared var
  String key = "ville";
  String txt_ville = "PARIS";
  List<String> villes = [];
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();

 //Location location;
  //LocationData locationData;
  //Stream<LocationData> stream;



  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getData();
    print(villes);
    super.initState();

    //location = new Location();
    //getFirstLocation();
  }

  /*getFirstLocation() async {
    try {
      print("Position: ${locationData.latitude}/${locationData.longitude}");
    }catch (e) {
      print("Error when locating $e");
    }
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _drawerKey,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: villes.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i) {
            return new ListTile(title: new Text(villes[i]));
          },
        )
      ),


        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex:4,
            child: new Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(120))
              ),
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                        child: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.dehaze, size: 30, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: () {
                          _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                        })),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                          child: new Text("TheWeatherApp", style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40
                            ),),
                        ),


                    ]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: new Container(
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  Future<Null> addTown() async{
    return showDialog(barrierDismissible: true, context: context, builder: (BuildContext buildcontext) {
      return new SimpleDialog(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        title: Text("Add a town"),
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(onPressed: () {

          }, child: new Text("Auto locate me"),),
          new TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Ville"
            ),
            onSubmitted: (s) {
              setData(s);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  void getData() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> liste = await sharedPreferences.getStringList(key);
    if (liste != null) {
      setState(() {
        villes = liste;
      });
    }
  }

  void setData(String str) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    villes.add(str);
    await sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, villes);
    getData();
  }

  void deleteData(String str) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    villes.remove(str);
    await sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, villes);
  }
}
```

I'm still a beginner on Flutter and I'm trying to understand why when I launch my application on the emulator and open my drawer with the iconbutton I get this error: [Pastbinlink to error](https://pastebin.com/09bBy6r8)

If I deliberately create an error in the code like removing a parenthesis and do a hotreload, and I put the parenthesis back and do a hotreload again then my code works and the listview is displayed...

I have a theory that it's my getData function that initializes the variable villes that doesn't work...

I thank you in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I am writing it as an answer.

I haven't tried your code, and I am not sure if it will work, however,

You should try to use [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

SharedPreferences.getInstance() is a future that will have value later on, and when you try to build your Drawer, it tries to access a value that doesn't exist.

Instead, if you try it like this. Your drawer will be created once your data is retrieved.

```dart
drawer: Drawer(
    child: new FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Center(child: Text("No data found."));
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i) {
                      return new ListTile(title: new Text(villes[i]));
                    },
                  )
                }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return checkError();
          }
          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }) 
    ),
```